# Merge data frames and include duplicate rows

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have several data frames, such as

```
>data1
     pearson     fisher      yates  mec
1 0.01141204 0.02857143 0.05777957 2.50
2 0.02609829 0.04761905 0.11203684 2.25
3 0.05280751 0.07619048 0.19670560 2.00
4 0.09742169 0.16666667 0.31998422 1.75
5 0.16754628 0.42857143 0.49015296 1.50
6 0.27332168 0.44444444 0.71500065 1.25
7 0.42919530 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00
8 0.65790502 1.00000000 0.65790502 0.75
9 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.29184055 0.50

> data2
     pearson     fisher     yates  mec
1 0.02609829 0.04761905 0.1120368 2.25
2 0.05777957 0.20634921 0.2059032 2.50
3 0.11203684 0.24242424 0.3403557 2.25
4 0.19670560 0.52380952 0.5186050 2.00
5 0.31998422 0.52380952 0.7402693 1.75
6 0.49015296 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.50
7 0.71500065 1.00000000 0.7150007 1.25
8 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.4291953 1.00
9 0.65790502 1.00000000 0.6579050 0.75
```

When I try to merge these two data frames, here is what I get:

```
> merge(data1, data2, all=TRUE)
      pearson     fisher      yates  mec
1  0.01141204 0.02857143 0.05777957 2.50
2  0.02609829 0.04761905 0.11203684 2.25
3  0.05280751 0.07619048 0.19670560 2.00
4  0.05777957 0.20634921 0.20590321 2.50
5  0.09742169 0.16666667 0.31998422 1.75
6  0.11203684 0.24242424 0.34035574 2.25
7  0.16754628 0.42857143 0.49015296 1.50
8  0.19670560 0.52380952 0.51860502 2.00
9  0.27332168 0.44444444 0.71500065 1.25
10 0.31998422 0.52380952 0.74026928 1.75
11 0.42919530 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00
12 0.49015296 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.50
13 0.65790502 1.00000000 0.65790502 0.75
14 0.71500065 1.00000000 0.71500065 1.25
15 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.29184055 0.50
16 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.42919530 1.00
```

I need to get 18 rows but instead I got 16, I have duplicate rows and I want to keep them in the data sets. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question the first time. I edited my response so that you get 18 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Ignore this answer. `merge` gives the desired output.

`rbind()` will put the two data frames together keeping all rows from both in the new data frame. Also, you would probably get more responses and timely responses if you retag your question with `r`.

First, getting your two data sets into `r`:

```
data1 = read.table(text = "
 pearson    fisher     yates      mec
 0.01141204 0.02857143 0.05777957 2.50
 0.02609829 0.04761905 0.11203684 2.25
 0.05280751 0.07619048 0.19670560 2.00
 0.09742169 0.16666667 0.31998422 1.75
 0.16754628 0.42857143 0.49015296 1.50
 0.27332168 0.44444444 0.71500065 1.25
 0.42919530 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00
 0.65790502 1.00000000 0.65790502 0.75
 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.29184055 0.50", sep = "", header = TRUE)

data2 = read.table(text = "
 pearson     fisher     yates  mec
 0.02609829 0.04761905 0.1120368 2.25
 0.05777957 0.20634921 0.2059032 2.50
 0.11203684 0.24242424 0.3403557 2.25
 0.19670560 0.52380952 0.5186050 2.00
 0.31998422 0.52380952 0.7402693 1.75
 0.49015296 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.50
 0.71500065 1.00000000 0.7150007 1.25
 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.4291953 1.00
 0.65790502 1.00000000 0.6579050 0.75", sep = "", header = TRUE)

data.merge = rbind(data1, data2)
```

Comment: this is not merging, this is binding.